# is there any way to encrypt data in hyperledger composer, like sha2 or sha3?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to encrypt some data and match it to other to make sure the data isn't changed, is there any way to do it, like sha256 or sha3. I try to use sha256 of nmp package but it not working, so how can I encrypt data in hyperledger composer???

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to access more advanced features, do not use composer. Composer will not have any features added to it and is only maintained to work with future version of Fabric.

Comment: thank Florian, it's very useful for me. I think I'll try another way in fabric